# How to mount '.img' file (extracted cubian file) in ubuntu

Tags: linux, mount

I used this command

```
sudo mount -t ext2 -o loop Cubian-desktop-r1-a20.img mountpoint
```

Output from this command is

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Comment: Try the `-r` flag as well.

Comment: no its not working

Comment: Are you sure that is an ext2 image? What is the output of `file Cubian-desktop-r1-a20.img`?

Comment: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

Comment: i have also tried with ext2,ext3,ext4 the same error is coming

Comment: It might not be any of the ext-series of filesystems. There are many filesystems in the world. It could be an ISO-9660 image, ZFS, ReiserFS, cramfs, HFS+ or a bunch of other things. Using the `file` tool (as Hauke Laging suggests above) can help identify which filesystem it is.